# href in scrollable div-container - link not working jumps to top of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I got a draggable div container with some dynamically generated content inside.

I call it with this code:

```
$( function() {
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 400,
    buttons: {
    Fertig: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
div#dialog-message {
background-color:#e8ebf3;
overflow:auto;
```

Inside the `div` I have other divs with href-links inside.
The links that are shown without scrolling do work fine, but when I scroll down in this container the hrefs does not work and the container scrolls automaticaly to the top when clicking.

The problem is that I use the `href` with an ID input from my database to toggle visibility of other div-containers like so:

```
<div href="651">This does not scroll</div>
```

Any ideas, how to combine the answers with this?

The href’s do work in Firefox, when I scroll down and click a link for the first time. But when I click it a second time without refreshing the page, it will scroll to the top.

In Chrome it doesn’t work a single time.

```
<div id="dialog"  href="651">First time clicking works, second time not.</div>
```

Problem solved:

The problem was that the page was not fully load when I tried to href to an div-Container witch did not exists at this point.

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You do need to make sure the href is not just #, Use an href like #void or so. Just having an href with # will make the page scroll to the top. An example:

`<a href="#">This will scroll to the top</a>`

`<a href="#void">This will not</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `<a href="javascript:void(0)">This does not scroll</a>`.